# Changing Resolution of Linux Framebuffer

Tags: linux, video, screen-resolution, framebuffer

I am writing a high performance video application in linux and C++ (but language shouldn't matter for this question)

I currently have my application such that I can display images to the Framebuffer.  When my computer boots, the resolution of the display connected seems to be set permanently.  I would like to be able to change the resolution output on the computer dynamically.  I have tried fbset but it did not work.  I am not using X11 because I assumed that there would be a performance decrease.

- Is directly writing to the framebuffer the best way to be doing my
  rendering for performance?
- If I use X11 I see that I can get commands
  to change the resolution.  Should this be something I investigate?
- Is there another way to change resolution?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: I thought X11 was mostly broken with respect to the tearing problem. They still don't swap the buffers during a sync (as I understand it, it is required to swap buffers during a vertical sync). See, for example, [What Is Screen Tearing and How to Get Rid of It on Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-rid-screen-tearing-linux/). Your best bet is probably avoid X11 and use something that's not broken.

Comment: @szatmary I updated it to remove the tearing question.